# How do I implement TouchScroll AS3 within Boundaries

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I am working within Flash, AS3 and I am trying to use a scroll function where I have a movieClip within a certain set of boundaries (i.e 400 x 800). The movie clip is 400 x 1200 but I wanted to know if there was a way of having the movieClip scroll within a boundary. I am publishing to android phone so it needs to be touch scroll. Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: set the max size of the parent container to 800

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**First option.** You should place your draggable MovieClip under mask, and drag it by the help of method [startTouchDrag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startTouchDrag%28%29), don't forget to pass touch identifier, don't lock to the center, and calculate right bounds, so it looks like:

```
function onTouchBegin(e:TouchEvent) {
    e.target.startTouchDrag(e.touchPointID, false, myBoundsRectangle); 
}
```

**Second option.** Don't use mask, but use [scrollRect](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scrollRect). You will need more calculations, because you will need register starting point from [TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TouchEvent.html#TOUCH_BEGIN), and offset your `scrollRect` from the `TOUCH_MOVE` event accordingly. But you will have more control, and you will be able to create easing animation.

Comment: I appreciate your answers, here is what i have so far:  ChestBiceps.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ClipDraggedOn);

var boundsRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(ChestBiceps.x, -100, 0, 1000);

function ClipDraggedOn(event:MouseEvent):void {
 ChestBiceps.startDrag(false, boundsRect);
 stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, ClipDraggedOff);
}


function ClipDraggedOff(event:MouseEvent):void {
 ChestBiceps.stopDrag();
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, ClipDraggedOff);
}

Comment: unfortunately the boundsRect doesnt seem to be limiting the movieclip, I am still able to drag the movieclip up off the stage. Do i need to position the boundsRect?

Comment: If you are able to drag it off screen, because you defined such bounds. For example, if you define `new Rectangle(biceps.x, biceps.y, 0, 100)` - you will be able drag `biceps` only along `y` axis, maximum on 100 pixels, from current position.

Comment: ok i now have -                                                     var boundsRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(ChestBiceps.x, ChestBiceps.y, 0, -300); But when i drag the movieclip up it does not scroll within a container it just scrolls up off the screen, it doesnt scroll within the parmeters similar to how it would with scrollBar component

Comment: If you want restrict it within some container, don't use magic number like `300`, calculate necessary max y offset. For your question, boundary box will be `new Rectangle(0,0,0, 1200-800)` if you movieClip is child of some container